# Jenkins Conditional Build

Tags: jenkins

I am completely new with Jenkins and have this question. So I created two projects on Jenkins. The first project will fetch from github if it notices any kind of change on my repo and will store a local copy on my machine.

The second project will start only if the first project is stable. If it is stable, the second project will first compile the all the java files (which I put in a compile.bat file), then it will run the testng.xml file which runs junit test and selenium test (run.bat file).

So what I want to do is if there is no compilation errors on compile.bat, then proceed on run.bat, but right now even though there are some errors on the java file and when the compile.bat runs, it catches those errors, Jenkins still proceeds to the run.bat file and at the end passes the build. I want the build to fail when there is any kind of errors.

Here is the link to my repo for the batch file and other files if that helps:
https://github.com/na2193/Demo

Answer (score 0):

I had figured it out. You need to use conditional step(single) and there you can define what you want to do